# No se como puedo salir del if despues del continue, ya que se hace un ciclo infinito

Tags: python

```
print ("Ingrese hasta que numero multiplo de 5 quiere sumar")
x= int(input())
y=5
num=x%y
while x>0:
    if num==0:
        print("Numero correcto")
        break
    if num!=0:
        print("Numero incorrecto, ingrese nuevamente")
        x= int(input())
        continue
```

Comment: Hola @william, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: El cálculo de `num` lo haces una sola vez fuera del bucle, y por tanto no tiene en cuenta el siguiente valor de `x` que el usuario pueda introducir, sino sólo el primer valor de `x` que introdujo, antes de entrar al bucle. Tienes que recalcular `num` tras leer la nueva `x`.

Answer (score 2):

Intenta esto:

```
print ("Ingrese hasta que numero multiplo de 5 quiere sumar")
x= int(input())
y=5
num=x%y
while x>0:
    if num==0:
        print("Numero correcto")
        break
    else:
        print("Numero incorrecto, ingrese nuevamente")
        x= int(input())
        num=x%y
        continue
```

Lo único que he echo ha sido cambiar tu `if num!=0:` por un `else`. También en el `else` después de pedir nuevamente el numero `x=int(input())`, he puesto de nuevo la operación `num=x%y`.

Lo he probado y funciona. Espero que te sirva.